# HTTPS Pages Not Loading

Tags: bug, ssl

Pages requested over HTTPS (https://stackoverflow.com/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23964427/1084749, etc) are not loading for me. In both Safari (logged in to SO) and Firefox (not), the browser just sits and loads nothing (I have waited ~10 minutes). The same URLs over HTTP load fine.

Comment: Weird things are happening 'cos service migration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23964427/1084749 loads for me. Seems to be an issue with https only?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't even noticed the HTTPS. It loads just fine with HTTP for me too.

Comment: Several have noticed the https problems:(

Comment: 'somehow, stack overflow doesn't work when I try to reach it over https. but only in chrome'

Comment: Totally relevant https://twitter.com/stackstatus/status/472829578994794496

Comment: more relevant http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233453/213575